# Inno Setup - Test DB connections with a Windows script

Tags: database-connection, inno-setup, windows-scripting

My goal is to be able to test a DB connection from Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, etc., ideally without installing any drivers (probably not possible).

I'm working on Inno Setup. The user would put the DB connection information there, and they would be able to test it before installing the app. I've tried using ADOConnection, but it only worked for SQL Server.

Is there a script command that could achieve what I want?

Comment: Your target not to install drivers is not achievable. For example, for MySQL you need ODBC drivers https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1055434/MySQL-ODBC-Driver-as-Dependency-in-InnoSetup-Packa

Comment: So ADOConnection is the right way to go but you need to explore what is necessary for each database you want to support

Comment: Thank you @demonplus for the response. I will see what I can do with ADOConnection, and later post a full response if I manage to do it